# How to Get data in Json using javascripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I'm currently creating an application to gather data form a website, and as I've researched you can used Json for that, now I have created a script to gather data, at first i have no problem with it, but when I cam across with a multi tree json i started having trouble.

here is my Json

```html
{
   "orders": [
      {
         "line_items": [
            {
               "id": 7660469767,
               "name": "Personalised design - purple",
               "properties": [
                  {
                     "name": "personalised text 1",
                     "value": "2"
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "personalised text 2",
                     "value": "Nuri &"
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "personalised text 3",
                     "value": "Samira"
                  }
               ],
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to get the order.line_items.properties.value.
I tried this code but it says it does not work.

```
$.getJSON(order.json, function (data) {
    $.each(data.orders.line_items.properties, function (index, value) {
        $.each(this.value, function () {
            console.log(this.text);
        });
    });
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `data.response.venue.tips.groups` doesnt seem to exist in your json??

Comment: Please check ur json on jsonlint its not an valid json

Comment: You might have problem with cross origin policy as well.

Comment: i've altered the json because of privacy issues, but understand I need to get value in orders.line_items.properties

Comment: `orders` is an array. So is `line_items`. So the properties of the first item in the first order would be `data.orders[0].line_items[0].properties`.

Comment: can I have the code to narrow down the json that will return value in properties

Comment: nnnnnn just gave it to you. `data.orders[0].line_items[0].properties[2].value === "Samira"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.orders[0].line_items[0].properties, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value.value);
});
```

Both `orders` and `line_items` are array, so it should have an access to array index first before accessing other object. And you don't have to use extra `each` in your code. The `value` above is an object for each `properties`. You can retrieve value there.